# FATAL Nuxt instance is unavailable

Tags: nuxt.js

I've just pulled from repo, ran `npm install` and then i run `npm run dev` now i get the error **FATAL  Nuxt instance is unavailable!** with the following:

```
 at useNuxt (/C:/Users/Work/example.com/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:50:11)
  at defineNuxtModule (/C:/Users/Work/example.com/node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:538:29)
  at /C:/Users/Work/example.com/node_modules/nuxt-webpack-optimisations/dist/module.mjs:266:16
  at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
  at async Promise.all (index 0)
  at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
  at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
  at async ModuleContainer.addModule (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:239:20)
  at async ModuleContainer.ready (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:51:7)
  at async Nuxt._init (node_modules\@nuxt\core\dist\core.js:478:5)
```

What does the error message above indicate? I never got this error message before.

Comment: Without some actual code, [repro] or context it will be quite hard to help you here. Try that one: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/1142 Also, be sure that you're running Node16 (especially if using Nuxt3).